# Approximately classify lines on image as vertical or horizontal

Tags: python, opencv, math, image-processing, computational-geometry

Suppose I have a list of coordinates for lines extracted with `cv2.HoughLinesP` from **edge mask** obtained from `cv2.Canny` edge detector.

```
lines = [[x1,y1,x2,y2] , ... ]
```

A line is classified as horizontal if its slope is within ±60◦ of the horizontal
direction. All other slopes are discarded.

A line is classified as a vertical if its slope is within ±5◦ of the vertical
direction. All other slopes are discarded.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def detect_line_angle(line):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line
    angle = np.arctan2(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
    # angle = angle * 180 / 3.14
    return angle


def get_lines_from_edge_mask(edge_mask):
    result = []
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edge_mask, 1, np.pi / 180, 30, maxLineGap=5)
    for line in lines:
        result.append(line[0])

    return result


def is_horizontal(theta, delta=1.05):
    return True if (np.pi - delta) <= theta <= (np.pi + delta) or (-1 * delta) <= theta <= delta else False


def is_vertical(theta, delta=0.09):
    return True if (np.pi / 2) - delta <= theta <= (np.pi / 2) + delta or (
            3 * np.pi / 2) - delta <= theta <= (
                           3 * np.pi / 2) + delta else False


def distance(line):
    dist = np.sqrt(((line[0] - line[2]) ** 2) + ((line[1] - line[3]) ** 2))
    return dist


def split_lines(lines):
    v_lines = []
    h_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        line_angle = detect_line_angle(line)

        dist = distance(line)
        if dist > 30:
            if is_vertical(line_angle):
                v_lines.append(line)

            if is_horizontal(line_angle):
                h_lines.append(line)

    return v_lines, h_lines
```

Is my function split_lines() correct with respect to the slope angle and h/v line direction?

**EDIT:**
Test image shows that there are a lot of miss-classified lines:
1)all the horizontal lines were pained green.
2)all the vertical lines were painted magenta.
[image: example]

Comment: @MarkSetchell This is not what I asked for...

Comment: Assuming `detect_line_angle` does what it claims to do, what do you need the test over `dist` for? And why such a complicated test for horizontality and verticality instead of a simple `-60 <= angle < 60` (with angle in degrees, ofc)?

Comment: @GPhile BECAUSE https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html returns an angle in radians, in the range [-pi, pi].

Comment: @YvesDaoust The guy provided a designer site link. As I mentioned earlier - this is NOT what I asked for.

Comment: @GPhilo `dist` is used for pruning the artifacts on the edge mask i.e. "short lines"

Comment: Then if numpy returns it in radians, just [`np.degrees`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.degrees.html) it?

Comment: @GPhilo Is that such a big problem - to manipulate angles in radians???

Comment: No, but your `is_*` function are overly complicated (and weirdly arranged) for what they ought to do, hence my question. Assuming you have an issue with your code - **and that's not even clear it's the case, since your question is "is my function correct?", which is off-topic for SO** - the source of it would be those test functions, because the rest is straightforward.

Comment: @arturkuchynski: I think you misunderstood why he provided this link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without intensive trigonometry using coordinate differences

```
t5 = tan(5*Pi/180) calculated once
t60 = Sqrt(3)/2 calculated once

Vertical: dy != 0 and abs(dx/dy) < t5
Horizontal: dx != 0 and abs(dy/dx) < t60
```

Comment: Simple and elegant answer. Thank you so much for that.